# Addressing "desirable" criteria that I do not meet in a job application

Tags: job-search, united-kingdom

I'm applying for a permanent lectureship at a UK university. The candidate brief has a list of essential and desirable criteria. I meet all of the essential criteria, but not the desirable criteria. The application form however, requires some sort of response to each of these criteria (the text boxes are mandatory and the form cannot be submitted without filling them in).

What should I write when asked for evidence I satisfy some criteria that I do not?

Example criteria:

Evidence of working with industrial partners

Evidence of conducting outreach activity

Comment: How many don't you really have an answer for?

Comment: If you don't have anything relevant to write, and the electronic form is just not letting you submit with them empty, a simple dash `-` is a reasonable way to say you have intentionally left a field blank. You can also generally write `N/A` meaning "not applicable", though in this context perhaps that might be interpreted as meaning you don't meet that criterion, rather than just that you don't have evidence of meeting it.

Answer (score 18):

This sounds like bad user interface design, but I totally understand why it could be really stressful.

If I were personally faced with this hurdle, I would be honest if I didn't meet a particular experience or competency, and say "I haven't had the opportunity yet, but would relish the chance to apply my research to an industrial context such as saving energy by predicting faults using my algorithm".

Perhaps it might be possible to put a nice spin on it and maybe show why you COULD do that thing, e.g. "No official outreach activity from academia, but I gave a presentation to a school class about my research into xyz (or wrote a blog post, contributed to an open source project, ...), demonstrating the skills to carry out outreach."

Comment: And, don't stress about not meeting a few criteria all that much - they are desired not required.

Comment: @JonCuster - good point, and it also doesn't mean the OP should give up. If they don't meet 3 reqs, maybe the next-best person fails to meet 4.

Comment: I agree with positive spin.  Another way you might consider it is by writing a thoughtful statement about how you might approach this in the future.  E.g. "I haven't had this opportunity yet, but I'm eager to try ... "

Answer (score 3):

Speaking from a relatively "fresh" Lecturer position in the UK here, so have gone through a similar application process (numerous times) about 2.5-3 years ago.

It is almost *expected* that some (most?) of the applicants will not satisfy some of the *desirable* criteria (as opposed to the *essential* ones). After all, the positions are often advertised jointly at the Lecturer / Senior Lecturer level, and while it is quite possible that the applicants at the Senior Lecturer level will have some experience with obtaining external funding, this is less likely for straight-out-of-postdoc applicants for Lecturer posts.

However, scoring the questions asked on the application form is used by the interview panel to determine the shortlist. The scores are recorded by the HR (to be available in case of any future disputes or enquiries about the hiring process). Therefore **I would strongly suggest not leaving those questions blank**. The panel will try and make sure their scoring reflects their actual opinion of the applicants, but addressing every question in some way will make this much easier on them.

So, try and see how the question is relevant to the position you are applying for, and address this as well as you can.

- Experience in obtaining external funding.

  A good answer for somebody with no experience would be to talk about UK funding bodies for your relevant discipline, to show that while you haven't obtained grant money yet, you know how to go about it.
- Evidence of working with industrial partners.

  I would say the key here is the opposing goals and requirements of research vs industry. So describing a strongly application-oriented project could be a good fit. Lacking anything like that, maybe describing any interdisciplinary work might be a bit of a stretch but somewhat fitting if you focus specifically on how you addressed the contrary requirements / communication gap.
- Evidence of conducting outreach activity.

  There is a strong push in the UK that researcher should be disseminated outside of individual "research bubbles". So anything related to presenting your work outside of your direct research community would fit here. It does not have to be as involved as "Robot programming workshops at the local school" - blog posts or open source projects could both work here if your answer focused on the aspects of those activities they are asking you about.

Of course, providing such answers to the questions about *desirable* criteria won't put you ahead if your answers about *essential* criteria do not clearly show you are a good fit. But if they are, investing some effort into thinking about what skills the *desirable* criteria are supposed to check for and evidencing those skills should only look good and help your application.

Comment: Having sat on the other side of the table I think that this is good: especially the para starting "However". To put it slightly cynically, you must make it as easy as possible for the subject experts who want to appoint you to argue round the HR folks who are ticking boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done in academia, but it's a pretty common thing in the field I'm in.  An advertised job description will list (say) 10 essential criteria and 5 nice-to-haves.

If I come close, it won't stop me from applying (hey, if you are a perfect match for their specs, there won't be much opportunity for personal growth).

If, for example, I meet 9 of the ten essential criteria, I'll point out how I'm such a great fit, never addressing the one I miss.  I try not to make what I have and don't have very obvious (mixing up the order, or addressing the list in a non-uniform manner).  I work on the assumption that the reader probably won't notice the one I'm missing.

When you get into the nice-to-haves, it's highly unlikely any of the candidates they are evaluating meet every criteria.  If I do meet spec, I'll point that out.
Otherwise, I'll generally look at the list and try to figure out where I might come close, or where there might be an overlap between my skill set and something that they might want that's close to what they are talking about: "While I've never done puffin farming, I did work with penguins for two years".

What you want to do is get close enough to the specs to advance to the next step without resorting to any falsehoods.

That they have textboxes for each criteria seems a bit rude to me (ok, maybe not rude, but...).  I'd leave the missing "desirable" ones blank or mostly blank (perhaps with a note: *"See my cover letter"*).  If there's a note anywhere with something like "if you need more space, please include an attachment", I'd just put "See Attachment" in each space and then create a hand-wavy attachment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't meet these requirements, it is best just to be up-front about that.  Those items then become an opportunity for you to demonstrate that you are candid, direct, and a straight-shooter.  Just be clear and succinct --- e.g.: "I have not previously undertaken work with industrial partners".

Answer (score 0):

Since they are desired I would explain a reason why something was not possible if there is any (i.e. outreach was not encouraged by my former employer) and then explain how you would approach such a point in the future: e.g. making sure the group webpage is up to date, starting a twitter account etc. Same for industry: no opportunity was up yet, but e.g. you plan to reach out to company X because they just published something similar to what you are doing or e.g. you plan to be part of a conference where industry is an essential part of to strengthen connections etc.

Of course, if you do this for 10 desired criteria this might not sound credible. For those points that you feel you do not want to address I would go with Felix U's answer to demonstrate that you are capable to to this.

Comment: I'd advise against explaining why you didn't have the opportunity to do something.  It comes of as whiney to me.

Comment: Interesting aspect, would you see this in all situations or just particular ones? For me an explanation like e.g. "my employer discouraged publications" or "my University did not agree to collaborations" would not be whiney but a simple fact and something I could not change. Something like: "I did not have the time because I was busy" would for me actually also come across as whiney and for such cases I do agree with you.

Comment: All situations.  Don't offer excuses before asked for them.  It sounds weak.  If someone *wanted* pubs enough, they would have found a way to get them.  If you don't buy that, then there's the issue that it serves to highlight a weakness that might have gone unnoticed.